# Register SimpleGraphQLServlet in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to add a GraphQLServlet to my existing webservice using [graphql-spqr](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr).

I have added the correct annotations and now only need to setup the GraphQL endpoint, which is where I am struggling.
All tutorials and google results that I found are referring to deprecated constructors for the class [graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet](https://github.com/Jahia/graphql-java-servlet/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/servlet/SimpleGraphQLServlet.java)

I can create a servlet object like this:

```
UserService userService = new UserService();
GraphQLSchema schema = new GraphQLSchemaGenerator()
                           .withOperationsFromSingleton(userService)
                           .generate();

graphql.servlet.GraphQLServlet servlet = new Builder(schema).build();
```

But I can't figure out if and how you can register a servlet instance.
And search engines either misinterpret my search or come up empty.

I'm grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Using Servlet 3+, you can dynamically register the servlet.  This is what I did for the exact same reason (I didn't want to use deprecated constructors).

```
@WebListener
public class GraphQLServletRegistrationServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private GraphQLSchema schema;

    public GraphQLServletRegistrationServletContextListener() {}

    @Inject
    public GraphQLServletRegistrationServletContextListener(final GraphQLSchema schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event) {
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dynamicGraphQLServlet
                = event.getServletContext().addServlet("GraphQLEndpoint", SimpleGraphQLServlet.create(schema));
        dynamicGraphQLServlet.addMapping("/graphql");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent event) {}

}
```

I'm using CDI to inject the GraphQLSchema, but you can just ignore that and construct it manually any way you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this also works with the new graphql-java-servlet 6.x (6.1.2 in my case), which uses SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet with a private constructor

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** As of graphql-java-servlet 6.x, this answer seems to be out of date

Unless you're using Spring, it's actually quite difficult to register a servlet instance yourself (and there's no standard way to do this), as the Servlet spec never really intended it to be used this way (the container is expected to take care of instantiating the servlets). And if you *are* using Spring, creating a servlet is unnecessary anyway. For this reason, using the `SimpleGraphQLServlet` is often unintuitive and inconvenient.

One way you can go about it is to subclass the `SimpleGraphQLServlet`, and let the container instantiate it for you as intended:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/graphql")
public class GraphQLEndpoint extends SimpleGraphQLServlet {

    public GraphQLEndpoint() {
        super(schema());
    }

    private static GraphQLSchema schema() {
       UserService userService = new UserService();
       GraphQLSchema schema = new GraphQLSchemaGenerator()
                       .withOperationsFromSingleton(userService)
                       .generate();
       return schema;
    }
}
```

You can also register `GraphQLEndpoint` the old-school way via `web.xml`.

You'll notice that you need to inline the entire setup as the call to `super` has to be the very first thing the constructor calls. This is what makes `SimpleGraphQLServlet` so inconvenient.

Another option is create your own servlet instead. There's really not that many things you need to do immediately. Just create the schema in its `init` method (no weird inline setup needed), store it in an instance field, and accept queries in `doGet` or `doPost`. There's of course the matter of handling errors, different URLs etc, which is a bit more complicated, but you don't need it right away for learning the basics.

You might also want to use a full-fledged framework, like Spring MVC or Boot. You can find an example of this in [graphql-spqr samples](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples).

Comment: graphql-java-servlet, as version 6.x SimpleGraphQLServlet does not exist anymore.

Comment: @linuxunil Not using graphql-java-servlet any more, so I can't update the answer. Sorry. Will add a disclaimer.

Comment: my intention is for the future readers not waste time to understand the error. I've spend 20 minutes to figure out. (library has no docs, no release notes, outdated readme..)